# how to make a function that take n as argument and create submatrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

hi everyone i stuck in a problem.i am going to make a function called quadrants that takes as its input argument a scalar integer named n. The function returns Q, a 2n-by-2n matrix. Q consists of four n-by-n submatrices. The elements of the submatrix in the top left corner are all 1s, the elements of the submatrix at the top right are 2s, the elements in the bottom left are 3s, and the elements in the bottom right are 4s.

thanks in advance for assistance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other approach with `bsxfun`, `reshape` and `permute`

```
function [ out ] = quadrants( n )
out = reshape(permute(reshape(bsxfun(@times,...
       ones(n,n,4),permute(1:4,[1 3 2])),n,2*n,[]),[1 3 2]),2*n,[]);
end
```

Results:

```
>> quadrants(3)

ans =

 1     1     1     2     2     2
 1     1     1     2     2     2
 1     1     1     2     2     2
 3     3     3     4     4     4
 3     3     3     4     4     4
 3     3     3     4     4     4
```

As the OP is desperate with `for` loop here is an alternate loopy approach

```
function [ out ] = quadrants( n )
out(2*n,2*n) = 0;
count = 1;
for ii = 1:n:2*n
    for jj = 1:n:2*n
        out(ii:ii+n-1,jj:jj+n-1) = count;
        count = count + 1;
    end
end
end
```

Results:

```
>> quadrants(2)

ans =

 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     2
 3     3     4     4
 3     3     4     4
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do it (try to avoid multiple "for" loops in matlab, it doesn't like them, try to use as much matrix as possible):

```
function[r] = Quadrant(n)
a = ones(n);
r = [a 2*a; 3*a 4*a];
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function [Q]=quadrant(n)
 W=zeros(n);
 X=ones (n);
Y= ones(n)*3;
Z= ones(n)*4;
V={[W], [X];
     [Y], [Z]}
Q=cell2mat(V)
end
```

Comment: You should explain your code a bit rather than just posting the code. Thanks!

Comment: This question already has a number of answers, including an accepted one, from over a week ago.  You may want to clarify what your answer does, especially why it is better than those already posted.